Not able to integrate Monaco code editor with Chrome extensjon
I am trying to integrate Monaco code editor for my chrome extension but the editor is not coming there. It shows error or it just keeps loading. The editor is working on npm run dev but not coming when I run as chrome extension. Please help me 
I tried playing with permissions in manifest file but nothing worked out
